Safest way to make a REST call from React using .env for storing the Auth token
I need to make a REST API call from inside the index.jsx of a React app.
I should mention that I did not create the app, I'm just trying to put some more functionality to an already made one, so, I know the app is using webpack and everything else needed to work correctly.
I have stored the Authentication token to the .env file and then I use it in the headers like so:
{headers: { "Authorization": `Token ${process.env.RESTUSERTOKEN}` } }

I don't want the token value to be visible to the client, but when I View the Page Source, and consequently the app.js from the browser, I can clearly see the full value of the token.
Is there any way to prevent this?

"Is there any way to prevent this?" - no. There's no safe way to do this from the client side.

What is your backend framework you are building your API in? Putting that framework tag would help find you the proper person to help you with this issue.

Actually the REST call is forwarded to a remote machine which is using Django-rest-framework, and that's where the REST API resides, but since it's not on the same server I think its framework is a bit irrelevant.
But as noted in one of the next answers, I might use a local API on the same server as React, creating it in Flask, as a middle tier for my remote API call.

It is not secure storing your API authentication token in .env files in ReactJS.
In frontend applications, environmental variables are bundled into the final JavaScript, so they are accessible in the inspect tools.
From your backend, I would send an HttpOnly cookie to your React application. This way, JavaScript can't access it on the page, which makes it more secure against cross-site scripting (XSS).
